# Riverpod - How to refresh() after an async function completes after the user has already left the screen

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, refresh, riverpod

I have a Flutter app that has a screen with a ListView of items that is supplied by a provider via an API call. Tapping an item goes to a second "detail" screen with a button (onPressed seen below) that will make an API call to complete an action. On success, the item is removed from the list by running refresh() to make the first API call again to get an updated list. However, if the user navigates away from the detail screen before the action is completed, executing the refresh is no longer possible and will throw the *"Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe"* exception. This is why I am first checking the mounted property, but is there any way in this scenario to execute the refresh? I am trying to avoid the confusion of the user seeing an outdated list and having to manually refresh. Thanks.

```
onPressed: () async {
    setState(() {
      // Disable the submit button
    });
    
    someAsyncFunction().then(
      (success) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (success) {
          // Success snackBar
          ref.refresh(someProvider);
          Navigator.pop(context);
        } else {
          // Failure snackBar
    
          setState(() {
            // Re-enable submit button
          });
        }
      },
    );
}
```